# Windows Speech Recognition Hello World not working

Tags: speech-recognition, c++-cx

I am trying to get `Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition` working on Windows10 but I have trouble making my Hello World App working.

Here is what I did:

- I created a new UWP Blank App in VS2017
- In the `OnLaunched()` method, I call my `Init()` method to initialize Speech Recognition:

  ```
  void App::Init()
  {
      speechRecognizer = ref new Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognizer(Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognizer::SystemSpeechLanguage);

      Platform::Collections::Vector<String^>^ speech_command_list = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<String^>();
      speech_command_list->Append(StringReference(L"pause"));
      speech_command_list->Append(StringReference(L"play"));
      speech_command_list->Append(StringReference(L"download"));
      speech_command_list->Append(StringReference(L"test"));

      SpeechRecognitionListConstraint^ speech_constraint = ref new SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(speech_command_list);

      speechRecognizer->Constraints->Append(speech_constraint);

      create_task(speechRecognizer->CompileConstraintsAsync()).then([this](SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult^ compilationResult)
      {
          if (compilationResult->Status == SpeechRecognitionResultStatus::Success)
          {

              speechRecognizer->ContinuousRecognitionSession->ResultGenerated += ref new TypedEventHandler<SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession^, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs^>(this, &App::OnSpeechRecognized);
              speechRecognizer->HypothesisGenerated += ref new TypedEventHandler<Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognizer^, SpeechRecognitionHypothesisGeneratedEventArgs^>(this, &App::OnHypothesisGenerated);
              speechRecognizer->StateChanged += ref new TypedEventHandler<Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognizer^, SpeechRecognizerStateChangedEventArgs^>(this, &App::OnStateChanged);
              speechRecognizer->RecognitionQualityDegrading += ref new TypedEventHandler<Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognizer^, SpeechRecognitionQualityDegradingEventArgs^>(this, &App::OnQualityIssue);

              TimeSpan endSilenceTime;
              endSilenceTime.Duration = 12000000L;
              speechRecognizer->Timeouts->EndSilenceTimeout = endSilenceTime; // (1.2 seconds in nanoseconds)

              speechRecognizer->ContinuousRecognitionSession->StartAsync();
          }
          else
          {
              // Handle errors here.
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- The code compiles, and launches, the compilation of speech constraints is successful, and I break once in the callback `OnStateChanged` with a new state value as `Idle`

And that's it. I do not receive any more callbacks when speaking into my mic.

For the record, my mic is properly plugged, it is the default mic on Windows, and it is functional.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was wrong on my application. I post here the answer in case anyone has the same issue.

It turns out that this type of UWP applications comes embedded with a file called Package.appxmanifest, that holds some settings of the application.

This manifest file has a "Capabilities" section, on which I had to turn on "Internet (client)" and "Microphone" capabilities.

After recompilation, everything was working fine.